# .htaccess rewrite query string in url

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am trying to use mod_rewrite to keep only the query string in a url, and remove index.php?p=.

For example, this link

```
http://domain.com/index.php?p=page-name-with-dashes
```

Into

```
http://domain.com/page-name-with-dashes.html
```

All pages are loaded through the control script index.php and the query p=name, like this

```
<?php
$page = isset($_GET['p']) ? $_GET['p'] : 'home';
...
require_once 'content-' . $page . '.php';
...
?>
```

I have tried all variants below, but none works - some give 404 some give 500 errors.

```
#RewriteRule ^index.php?p=(.*) $1/

#RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]

#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?p=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

What am I doing wrong? I don't know much about htaccess rules, so forgive my newbie question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*).html$  index.php?p=$1 [L]
```

But be aware that if you have multiple cases (for example some other type of url to rewrite) be careful with ordering of RewriteRules because you could easily override one with another...

Comment: With a small modification, it worked: RewriteRule ^(.*).html$ index.php?p=$1 [L]

Comment: I am sorry, I just copied one of lines from my last project .htaccess file. And did not modified it well, so I edited my answer now :)